# Ошибка LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, линковка

Делаю задание по учебнику. Необходимо создать 3 файла:

my.h:

```
#pragma once
extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

my.cpp:

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>
#include "my.h"

void print_foo()
{
    cout << foo << '\n';
}

void print(int i)
{
    cout << i << '\n';
}
```

use.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my.h"

int main()
{
    foo = 7;
    print_foo();
    print(99);

    char cc;
    std::cin >> cc;
}
```

Ошибки:

> my.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""int foo" (?foo@@3HA)"
>   use.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""int foo" (?foo@@3HA)"
>   E:\Projects\OWN\C++\Программирование. Принципы и практика с использованием C++\8\Задание\1\Debug\1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а где *определение* `foo`? E вас только объявление, в вольном переводе

```
extern int foo;
```

звучит - "работай, считая, что `int foo;` есть, только где-то в другом месте. Я его там определю".

Но обещание не выполнено - ни в одном .cpp-файле нет простенького

```
int foo;
```

или там

```
int foo = 10;
```

Выполните обещанное :)

Comment: Добавил в use.cpp:
int foo = 7;
Осталась вот эта ошибка:
1>my.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""int foo" (?foo@@3HA)"

Comment: Надеюсь, добавили там же, где и объявляли - в глобальной области видимости? Или вы определили *локальную* `foo` в `main`, которую за пределами `main()` никто никогда не увидит?...